# Dúvida no uso da função to_string

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, c++11

Em um exercício que estou fazendo, foi proposto ler dois números, um inteiro e um real, e contar quantos dígitos eles tem.

A entrada e saída deverá ser assim:

```
Entre com o numero inteiro: 2345

Entre com o numero real: 234.549

O numero inteiro possui 4 dígitos.

O numero real possui 6 dígitos.
```

Estou usando esse código para resolver o problema:

```
//Entrada de numeros

cout << "Entre com o numero inteiro: ";
cin >> NumInt;
cout << "Entre com o numero real: ";
cin >> NumReal;
//Conversao para string
NumString = to_string(NumReal);

//Contador de digitos
while (NumString[i++] != '\0');

//Impressao do numero
cout << endl;   
cout << "Numero lido: " << NumString << endl;
cout << "Possui " << i - 1 << " digitos." << endl;
```

A saída é essa:

```
Entre com o numero inteiro: 1234

Entre com o numero real: 765.34

Numero lido: 765.340027

Possui 10 digitos.

Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

O número real está sendo lido com dígitos a mais. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Quais os tipos de `NumInt`, `NumReal`  e `NumString`? Tem como mostrar as suas declarações?

Comment: Sim, claro. 
int NumInt;
float NumReal;
string NumString;

Answer (score 0):

Aumente a precisão de `NumReal` substituindo o seu tipo de:

```
float NumReal;
```

Para:

```
double NumReal;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, vou testar aqui.